# How do I stop an infinite prompt loop without using Break?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, break

I've created an infinite loop with a `prompt` in order to insert city names into an `array` as long as you wish, however I would like to stop this infinite loop whenever the user hits cancel in the `prompt` without using a `break`.

```
<script>
    var cities = new Array(); 
    var i=0; 

while(i >= 0){ 
    i++; 
    cities[i] = prompt("Type a City");
    if (cities[i] == null) break; 
document.write("<tr> <td>" + i + "</td> <td>" + cities[i] + "</td> </tr>")  
</script>
```

after

> if (cities[i] == null) break;

What else could I add other than `break`?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `break`? This is exactly what it's for if you want to run until the user's finished. By the way, you're skipping index 0.

Comment: wrap it in a function and use a `return` statement. But as @Kristján mentioned - `break` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Kristján Some of my teachers said they wont accept `break` statements, so I wanted an alternative way to stop the loop. I didnt notice I skipped 0, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Tell your teachers the internet says arbitrary, nonsensical rules are harmful. On the other hand, try not to use `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set i to -1 instead of break

Below is the code:

```
var cities = new Array(); 
var i=0; 

while(i >= 0){ 
    i++; 
    cities[i] = prompt("Type a City");
    if (cities[i] == null) {
       i = -1; 
    } else {
       document.write("<tr> <td>" + i + "</td> <td>" + cities[i] + "</td> </tr>");
    }
}
```